# How to stop hammer.js event propagation

Tags: hammer.js

How to stop event propagation in Hammer.js (2.0.2)? The technique used in the relevant test (https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/blob/master/tests/unit/test_propagation.js) does not apply to all type of events. If you replace the 'tap' event with a 'press' one, the test fails.

Comment: FWIW the technique in the unit test works fine for swipe events, so thank you @nlyk for bringing it to my attention! Hammer.js guys, it seems a shame that the new shiny version of the library makes it harder to do this than before.

Comment: The tips and tricks page http://hammerjs.github.io/tips/ describes that you need to set option {domEvents: true} in order to enable stopPropagation. I haven't got this working so far

Answer (score 1):

In your parent element check what the event.target is. If it is not the parent element and is set to the child then ignore the event.

eg: 
    if(event.target != parent){
      return;
    }

Comment: It's just a workaround but it worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue I wrote a small mixin to extend hammer.js with event propagation:

https://github.com/josdejong/propagating-hammerjs

Comment: Do you know what was the motivation to rewrite hammer.js that way? why the events are not bounded to the DOM?

Comment: Performance can be better if you just have JS and no DOM. And it's easier to build without having to reckon with the DOM. It's also not a very common use case to need event propagation, and it's sort of an anti pattern in favor of event delegation having a single parent handling all events. But sometimes it *really* makes your life easier. It can be necessary when having self-contained components.

Answer (score -1):

In your parent dom bind click event, and stopPropagation it